# How exactly work the LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean configuration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have the following doubt about how to use **JPA 2** in Spring.

Reading on the documentation I find that exist 3 ways to set up an **EntityManagerFactory** that provide me an **EntityManager** used as a bridge between the OO model to the DB relational model.

These 3 ways are:

1. **LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean**
2. **LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean**
3. **Use a JNDI lookup**

So now I have some doubts about the first one (the **LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean**). Reading on the documentation I find that this method is **useful for standalone apps, integration tests** (what exactly means as standalone apps?) and that **it cannot specify a DataSource**, in particular about this last statment:

- **It is useful when only data access is via JPA**
- **Uses standard JPA service location (SPI) mechanism**
  /META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

What exactly means al thiss stuff? I know that JPA 2 is used to map a class to a DB table and to perform easily the interaction on the DB. What menas that this way to to set up an **EntityManagerFactory** cannot specify a DataSource? I think that if I am using JPA 2 I am working on a DB so I need a data source.

What am I missing?

Then I have also the following code snippet example related to the **EntityManagerFactory** configuration into a Spring configuration class:

```
@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean em =
    new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setPersistenceUnitName(“rewardNetwork”);
    return em;
}
```

So what exactly do this bean configuration? How it works?

Tnx